# How to limit calls to external API in django

Tags: python, django

I have an app that displays all the posts of a YouTube-Channel. For that, I use the youtube-API v3 which I call in my views.py. I then save all the data in my database which I pass as context to my render-function:

`return render(request, "blog/home.html", context)`

I was wondering if it's possible to only call the API if the last API-call was 5 minutes ago and just use the data in the database otherwise.

One idea I have is to save the current datetime to a file whenever an API-call is made, and whenever the views-function is called, compare the current datetime with the one in the file. However, this seems inefficient and I was wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: Django has some built-in cache methods.

Comment: @KlausD. Thanks, worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something similar to what you described not sure if this would be any help to you. For mine it can only request again per minute

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def api_get_cha3_price(request):
response_data = {}
# Get Cha3 price and the logics

d = CryptoPrice.objects.get(name='CHA3')  # get the last updated time
d = d.date.replace(tzinfo=None) + timedelta(hours=8,
                                            seconds=3)  # +8 hours because it's malaysia time and 1 minute is so that if > 1 minute can request again
d1 = datetime.now()

cha3 = CryptoPrice.objects.get(name='CHA3')

if d1 > d:
    import time
    try:
        timestamp = int(time.time() * 1000)
        response = requests.get(
            f"API_URL",
            timeout=2)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            data = response.json()

            cha3.price = data['data'][0]['price']
            cha3.date = timezone.now()
            cha3.save()

            cha3_price = cha3.price

            response_data["cha3_price"] = f"{cha3_price}"

    except(requests.exceptions.Timeout, requests.exceptions.ConnectionError, KeyError, TypeError):
        cha3_price = cha3.price
        response_data["ERROR"] = f"{cha3_price}"

else:
    cha3_price = cha3.price
    response_data["cha3_price"] = f"{cha3_price}"
return Response(data=response_data)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I was able to solve it using Klaus D.'s comment about the built-in cache method